# Is it possible to use Not In With This Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to view a list of boxes that are in our master list, but have not been marked off-site in our offsite list.

```
Select boxID, boxlocation
From masterList
WHERE boxlocation NOT IN (
                           Select boxID FROM offsiteList
                         )
```

However, either my 2 lists have become very corrupted or my query is returning inaccurate results.  Wanted to check this was a good query before I went line by line check of the list...

Comment: Yes... however Logically boxlocation will not equal boxID.  Either the where clause needs to be `WHERE boxID` or the subselect needs to be `Select boxLocation`.  This issue is not corrupt data; rather you're comparing Boxes to Locations (apples to oranges) invalid compare logically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're filtering on the wrong field; presumably `boxID` is the field which matches records in each table; so the one you should compare on.

```
Select boxID, boxlocation
From masterList
WHERE boxID NOT IN 
(
    Select boxID 
    FROM offsiteList
)
```

Also, if the `offsiteList.boxID` column has nulls, the NOT IN predicate will not work as expected. You will need to filter out the nulls in the subquery:

```
Select boxID, boxlocation
From masterList
WHERE boxID NOT IN 
(
    Select boxID 
    FROM offsiteList
    WHERE boxID IS NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1):

PLEASE learn "exists" and "not exists" for any non-ad-hoc queries.
Please.

```
    Select boxID, boxlocation
    From masterList ml

    where not exists
    (select null

 from offsiteList innerQueryOSL where innerQueryOSL.boxID = ml.boxID )
```

Comment: Care to teach the OP *why* s/he should prefer this form over the other?

Comment: I have seen it firsthand where exists and not exists performs much better.  There are a handful of references on the internet which say "it does not matter", I've seen it matter.  I don't have the proprietary code to show....but I know it happened because my former-developer-now-manager boss said "it doesn't matter", and I showed him the test results.......then he got quiet all the sudden.  I no longer work there because he was the kind of guy who always thought he was right, even though his programmings skills stopped at vb6/vb.net code and sql server 2005.

Comment: The exists and not-exists also subtly teaches you that the inner-query can reference the outer-query.  And while this query only had one column.......if you needed to based it on 2 columns....  Here is a kind of made up query......using "pubs".......but shows the point.        Use pubs
Go

Select st.stor_id , ti.title_id  from [dbo].[stores] st , [dbo].[titles] ti
where not exists (
 select null from [dbo].[sales] innerSal where innerSal.stor_id = st.stor_id  and innerSal.title_id = ti.title_id )

Answer (score -3):

USE Not EXISTS instead of NOT IN:

```
Select boxID, boxlocation
From masterList
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                           Select boxID FROM offsiteList
                         )
```